# Python time module won't handle year before 1900

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert date of birth from a text file.Let's say, I have data

```
fjsffk 1985-01-30
fkgskgks 1899-02-20
```

I have tried with the following code, still getting error:

```
import datetime

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
          'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        dob = line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]  
        dt = datetime.strptime(dob, "%Y-%m-%d")          
        print "{0:} {1:}, {2:}".format(months[dt.month-1], dt.day, dt.year)
```

Any solution please, thanks!

Comment: `time` and `datetime` modules are two different things in Python. Your title mentions *datetime* but your code uses *time* and again, one of the proposed solutions uses *datetime*. Maybe you would like to edit your question and clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per python [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-strptime-behavior)

> The exact range of years for which
>   strftime() works also varies across
>   platforms. Regardless of platform,
>   years before 1900 cannot be used.

Please bear with me - i have tried the following solution and it works fine for me:

```
from datetime import datetime

mDt = datetime(1900,01,01)
dt = datetime.strptime('20-02-1899', "%d-%m-%Y")
resultString = datetime(dt.year + (mDt - dt).days/365 + 1, dt.month, dt.day).strftime('%B %d, %Y').replace('1900', str(dt.year))
```

OR something like this:

```
monthes = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
dt = datetime.strptime('20-02-1890', "%d-%m-%Y")
print "{0:} {1:}, {2:}".format(monthes[dt.month-1], dt.day, dt.year)
```

Comment: Could you please check this line `dt = datetime.strptime('20-02-1890', "%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: I have tried this code both in Python 2.6 console and PyCharm and it works fine for me. What error did you actually get?

Comment: Attributes error: type object 'date-time.date_time ' has no attributes for strptime

Comment: Ok what python version do you use? Also note that if you want you can find my skype and contact me directly.

Comment: Please let me know, when you usually remain free to talk on skype.Thanks!

Comment: I am free for chat almost always.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a previous post that may have some ideas for you:
[formatting-date-string-in-python-for-dates-prior-to-1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526170/formatting-date-string-in-python-for-dates-prior-to-1900)